# Primefaces Chat Application - web.xml Invalid content was found starting with element

Tags: java, primefaces, chat, tomcat7, web.xml

I want to implement the PF 3.5 [Chat Application](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.jsf) on a `tomcat 7` server. I have added that dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
    <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

However, I when I implement that `web.xml`:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
```

...

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.HeaderBroadcasterCache</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcastFilterClasses</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.client.TrackMessageSizeFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.sessionSupport</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

As an excpetion I get:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'init-param'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/
 xml/ns/javaee":run-as, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":security-role-ref}' is expected.
```

btw I get the exception at the `<init-param>` tag.

I really appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

I get the same excpetion when I just write that:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>channels</param-name>
        <param-value>chat,counter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/prime-push/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I also get the expcetion at the `<init-param>` tag

Answer (score 20):

According to the [schema](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd) the order matters. So `<load-on-startup/>` element should come after the  `<init-param/>` element.

eg.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>channels</param-name>
        <param-value>chat,counter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Thx, I had similar problem and putting <load-on-startup/> after init param did the trick! +1 for you

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, order matters, For PF Push Servlet & atmosphere this setup is good starting point:

```html
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxProcessingThreads</param-name>
        <param-value>15</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxAsyncWriteThreads</param-name>
        <param-value>15</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```